# Where do I store session id in vue.js

Tags: vue.js

So basically I have a simple vue app that is going to make requests to an API.
As there is no authentication, I need to make sure that during the vue app's life cycle (basically while the browser is open) the app will have access to some unique identifier that can be sent to the server.

In this way, the API will understand that it is the same "user" that is making requests.

As Im totally new to vue Im not really sure how I can accomplish this.
My first idea was to add code inside some global file (for example /src/App.vue) that could look like this:

```
if(!window.localStorage.getItem('session_id')){
    let random = Array(5).fill().map(n=>(Math.random()*36|0).toString(36)).join('')
    window.localStorage.setItem('session_id', random)
}
```

And then, when making API requests, I would attach it this way:

```
//pseudo code
request.header('session_id', window.localStorage.getItem('session_id')).get('endpoint1')
```

Is this the way to go? Or there are better ways?

Comment: you have different possibilities, store them in local storage or use vuex store or pinia store

Comment: I suggest persist on local storage, or use a package that persists vuex store (like this https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuex-persist you can configure which properties to store). The vuex store in cleaned when you refresh the page.